# Why is the definition of opportunity cost "the benefit of the best alternative choice" but not "the benefits of all alternative choices combined"?

Tags: microeconomics, definition

What is the rationale behind it?

Answer (score 3):

This is because it does not make sense to compare chosen options to all other alternatives that are mutually exclusive. For example, if you have 5 choices A, B, C, D, E, you can choose one, and C is the most preferred option it does not make any sense to compare picking C to jointly picking A, B, D and E. Only one of the other options can be pick so you should use best of them for comparison